# Why do I get impossible values when I calculate proportion of forest edge inside of grid cells?

Tags: r, polygon, raster, r-raster

I have a raster of land cover data and a shapefile of grids (found [here](https://github.com/lilactoad/forestedge)), which I have clipped down for the purpose of this question. The raster is from NLCD and has been reclassified so that all forest types are in one class.

I want to calculate the proportion of forest edge that is in each grid cell from my shapefile. I have attempted to do so with the code below and the `landscapemetrics` package.

```
#load packages 
library(raster)
library(landscapemetrics)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

#NLCD 2019 reclassified (all forest 1 class)
NLCDNYrc <- raster("NLCDNYrc.tiff")

#read in grid file
twokm_grid <- readOGR(dsn = "NY Grid", layer = "allNY_2point7225km2_grid_exploded")
#transform CRS
twokm_grid <- sp::spTransform(twokm_grid, CRS("+proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))

#extract forest edge from NLCD reclassified data on a 2.7km2 scale
edge_2km_grid <- sample_lsm(NLCDNYrc, twokm_grid, level = "class", metric = "ed")

#subset out just forest edge
edge_2km_grid_forest <- subset(edge_2km_grid, class == 40)
```

However, the output I get in the "value" column has values ranging from 0-280 and the "percentage_inside" column has values ranging from 60-260. Why are there such high values? I am under the impression that the "value" range should be from 0-1 and the "percentage_inside" range should be from 0-100.

Any ideas what is going wrong here? or alternative suggestions for calculating forest edge?

Comment: Please edit your question to create, as much as possible, a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*. **Minimal** means that you only include code that is needed to understand the problem. For example, do not load packages that are irrelevant to the example. **Self-contained** means that you illustrate the problem with data that is generated with code or by using data that ships with R; see the help files for examples; only use downloads if the problem is related to the specific file. **Reproducible** means that you illustrate the problem with R code --- do not just describe it.

Comment: I have made this as minimal and reproducible as possible as I can for my skill level in R. I wanted to include the specific files I am using in case the problem is relevant to them

Comment: Thank you, that is much better.  Unfortunately, I cannot help without looking at the data. Perhaps you can show `head(edge_2km_grid_forest)`?